# Get MAX value of count of each dept after group by clause on dept and grade

Tags: sql

My query gets count of employee for each dept for each grade .

```
select dept , grade , count(1) CNT
from mytable 
group by dept , grade
order by dept , cnt desc;
```

now i need from that the grades getting max count  of each dept .

output should be

```
dept  grades MAX(count)
```

how can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: What rdbms are you using? (MySql,Oracle,Sql-Server,...)?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using the `row_number()` function:

```
select dept, grade, cnt
from (select dept, grade, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by dept order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from mytable t
      group by dept, grade
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```